# How Gitlab executors manage installed dependencies?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

If I have for example shell executor on Gitlab on my own and install Java in one job, will this Java be available also in next job?

And what about other types of runnera?

Answer (score 0):

Executors don't exactly have a direct role in managing installed dependencies. The environment either has or does not have particular software pre-installed. The short answer is: **runners do not manage installed software** in any way. A (shell) runner will neither install or remove software. So, if you install software through shell commands in a job, that software should remain installed.
But to completely understand the answer to whether or not installing dependencies in one job will persist to the next is dependent on how you have deployed your runner, the type of executor you are using, and other details like how you install the software.

If you use the `shell` executor and install a package (for example, like `apt install ...`) then subsequent jobs **on that exact same runner host** *should* still have the package installed (unless a subsequent operation removes/upgrades the package). However, you must still consider that you may not always be using the same host, for example if you have multiple or shared runners configured or if the host is replaced at some point in time. In some cases, even if using the `shell` executor, the host may actually be ephemeral, such as in certain autoscaling scenarios.

If you are using a docker-based executor or certain executors with an otherwise disposable environment, typically you must rely on the specified `image:` to contain any dependencies. Every job starts in a new container, so installing dependencies (for example by running `apt install ...`) won't persist between jobs. Some caveats may apply, like when volumes are mounted from the host to the job container.

Comment: "A (shell) runner will neither install or remove software. So, if you install software through shell commands in a job, that software should remain installed." -  so it will install it by shell or not?

Comment: additionally I can see that for example if I will set some changes to PATH in shell , it is not saved in next job

Comment: @ruddnisrus yes, you can install software in a shell runner. It also depends how you install the software. If you're not using the system package manager (e.g., `apt`, `apk`, `dnf`, `yum`, or similar), that may not work as you intend. Keep in mind, subsequent jobs may not be guaranteed to run on the same host. This would only be practical in a situation where you have exactly 1 registered runner for the jobs you want with persisted system state.

Comment: @systech - and what about for example PATH set? I have only one instance and I can see that every job path is hmm "reset" to original state despite of fact that I change it

Comment: @MateuszKaleta it depends on the operating system and other details... For example, on Windows powershell shell runners, every job is started with the `-NoProfile` flag, hence changes to PATH or other variables will not persist across jobs, unless you set the variable system level variable. On Linux systems, PATH modifications typically take place in a user's bash profile (e.g., a `.bashrc` or similar file) to stay persisted. In GitLab CI you may need to ensure `BASH_ENV` is set to the correct location to load the correct user profile. You must also not override PATH in the runner config.

Comment: But generally you don't need to rely on PATH modifications for properly installed software on Linux because binaries _should_ be installed to (or symlinked from) a common default locations that are already on PATH such as `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, or `/usr/local/bin`. For Windows, you want to set the PATH at the system level to ensure binaries are on PATH after being installed... If you want to edit your question or ask a separate question providing more details about what you're trying to do and what is not working, I can try to edit my answer to answer those additional aspects @MateuszKaleta